# Area webapi route not being resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

am trying to test the web api routes, that exists inisde my administration area.

This is the the route definition in the area

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("timezone/put/{timezone}", Name = "PutTimeZone")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutTimeZone(string timezone)
   {
     /*Action body*/
   }
```

I have a route prefix like so **[RoutePrefix("admins/misc")]**

Here is my route test

```
 const string route = "/admins/misc/timezone/put/-120";
        RouteAssert.HasApiRoute(_httpConfiguration, route, HttpMethod.Put);

        _httpConfiguration.ShouldMap(HttpMethod.Put, route)
            .To<MiscApiController>(HttpMethod.Put, x => x.PutTimeZone("-120"));
```

When I run the test, I get `MvcRouteTester.Assertions.AssertionException : Expected 'Administration', got no value for 'area' at url '/admins/misc/timezone/put/-120'.`

I read in the [route tester wiki page](https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester/wiki/Usage)

> If you are using MVC areas, then as long as you use the standard
>   layout of namespaces, the area name will be extracted from your
>   controller type name and tested against the area chosen by the route.
>   e.g. if your controller's fully qualified type name is
>   `MyWebApp.Areas.Blog.CommentController` then the expected area name will
>   be "Blog".

But frankly, it doesn't give me any clue as to what to do so as to make my test pass. My question is what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `[RoutePrefix("admins/misc")]` with `[RouteArea("Administration",AreaPrefix = "admins/misc")]` or combining both together with `[RouteArea("Administration",AreaPrefix = "admins"),RoutePrefix("misc")]`.

**Edit:**
I downloaded the source for the `MvcRouteTester` library and tried to debug it using almost the same example as you provided and it looks like there is an issue with the library itself.

Specifics: one method `Common.Verifier.VerifyExpectations` asserts that  the expected area `expected.Area` matches route's actual area `actual.Area`, but there is no previous code that sets the actual area property to any value (although it does set Controller and Action properties in `ApiRoute.Generator.ReadRequestProperties`).

So I suppose that at its current state (at the time of this post) the library simply does not support areas for `WebApi`. I suggest that you open an issue on the MvcRouteTester github page with a link to this post.

Comment: but route area is specifically meant for Asp.net Mvc and there seems not to be Webapi variant, Is right for it to be used inside webapi controller

Comment: tried it anyway and the test is still failing with the same exception message as shown above.

Comment: I didn't realise that and I am not sure what the answer is, sorry. I never tried using ApiController inside the area so far. The other thing that comes to mind though is what is your ApiController's namespace? If I understand the wiki docs you provided correctly, the expected namespace is `YourProjectName.Areas.Administration`. Can you verify that?

Comment: Maybe you're right and there's no sense in using `RouteAreaAttribute` for ApiController. In that case, since the wiki docs explicitelly mentions 'If you are using _MVC areas_...' for describing how it works with them, then using areas with _Web API_ is not supported at all.

Comment: Nope, it is, as it also not only caters for mvc but also for webapi, if you read it down, you will see it also makes provisions for webapi

Comment: I updated the answer - I think there may be an issues with the library for your scenario.

Comment: Maybe, but the wiki page, whose link I provided states otherwise. Anyway I will keep on searching.